# Correct/Fast Way to Change the Config of a Command-Line Qt5 Source Build

Tags: c++, qt, build, qt5

I'm building Qt5 (Qt 5.15.0) from source (the official source releases, not from repo) on Windows with MSVC.

I'm setting up the env. variables, the dependencies, etc. and then run `configure` with 16 million options, and finally `jom` and it works.

But I'm experimenting with the build, and have to run `configure` a lot. And it seems like each time I either have to delete the whole source tree and re-unpack, or the build would fail.

Specifically, is there a way to "unconfigure" or "reconfigure" a Qt5 build? The "-redo" flag doesn't seem to be it, and `nmake clean` or `jom clean` don't work either (and they don't seem to be what I want; I want reconfigure, not rebuild.)

Again, note that my build does work. I just want faster/more practical iteration over changing the build configuration.

Comment: I keep the source in a folder and build in a totally different tree.

Comment: I use shadow build i.e. running configure.bat from one directory up. That way I can delete the shadow build folder and rerun the configure or make. But don't know if there is way to clean up the stuff without deleting the shadow build folder.

Comment: It seems to me that `configure` and build put some files in the `qtbase` directory (and probably elsewhere.) Does this "running the configure form another directory" actually work for you? I.e. does it let you run configure with totally different set of options?

Comment: Well, before re-configuring the QT build, I deleted the shadow build folder. Tested on both Linux and Windows and it seems same.

Comment: This was my cmdline for Linux build. Here you can clearly see that I have ran the cmd from one directory up level. `$ ../qtsrc/configure -opensource -confirm-license -release -static -no-pch -qt-xcb -prefix $PWD/_build -skip webengine -nomake tests -nomake examples`. So in case I need to do another configure I would just delete the 
 `$PWD`

Comment: Hey, thanks! I did it, and it seems to be working (it's building, and the config/build process has made a lot of files in the "shadow" directory and not the source directory.) If you would please put this in an answer so I'd be able to accept it, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use shadow build i.e. execute configure from one directory up level. Here is my command line which I used on Linux to build Static QT.

```
$ ../qtsrc/configure -opensource -confirm-license -release -static -no-pch -qt-xcb -prefix $PWD/_build -skip webengine -nomake tests -nomake examples
```

So in case you need to do another configure just empty the directory $PWD. Hope it helps to close this question.